# Not Refreshing Spesific Label While Binding ObservableCollection Listview in Xamarin & MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, observablecollection

```
public class Zicker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string HeyName { get; set; }
        public string HeySurname { get; set; }
        public int HeyAge { get; set; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _yourList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> YourList
    {
        get
        {
            return _yourList;
        }
        set
        {
            _yourList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("YourList");
            RaisePropertyChanged("BindMeLabel");
        }
    }

    public int BindMeLabel
    {
        get { return _yourList.Sum(a => a.HeyAge); }
    }

    public void WonCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("BindMeLabel");
    }

    public List<string> heresamplenames = new List<string> { "Mohamed", "Zaran", "Ivan" };
    public List<string> heresamplesurnames = new List<string> { "Pakou", "Simmone", "Zagoev" };
    public List<int> heresampleages = new List<int> { 17,33,50 };

    public Zicker()
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyClass> vs = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        { vs.Add(new MyClass { HeyName = heresamplenames[i], HeySurname = heresamplesurnames[i], HeyAge = heresampleages[i] }); }
        YourList = vs; YourList.CollectionChanged += WonCollectionChanged;
    }
}

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <ContentView HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <ListView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=HeyName}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=HeySurname}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <Entry HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Path=HeyAge}" FontSize="12" Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ContentView>
        <Label Text="{Binding BindMeLabel}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="40" TextColor="Black"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new Zicker();
    }
```

My Problem: In this List, there are three names, surnames, and ages. At the bottom, there is also a label which should be shown as the sum of Ages collection.

When the UI is starting, Label is working well. But, if I try to change any Ages entries, there is a big problem with the binding label.

I want to use MVVM structure but due to this problem, label binding is working just start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating the `HeyName` property, binding is not updating because the class `MyClass` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Try to replace the `MyClass` class with this code:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private string surname;
    private int age;

    public string HeyName
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("HeyName");
        }
    }

    public string HeySurname
    {
        get => surname;
        set
        {
            surname = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("HeySurname");
        }
    }

    public int HeyAge
    {
        get => age;
        set
        {
            age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("HeyAge");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, the `CollectionChanged` is not called when you update the `HeyAge` property, because it is called only if the collection is changed, but **not** when a property of an item in the collection changes.

Try to add the `OnAgeChanged` event into the class `MyClass` and call it when the `HeyAge` property change:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler OnAgeChanged;

    public int HeyAge
    {
        get => age;
        set
        {
            age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("HeyAge");
            OnAgeChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Then, when you add a new `MyClass` object into the collection, register the event in the `ViewModel` like this:

```
public Zicker()
{
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> vs = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var test = new MyClass()
        {
            HeyName = heresamplenames[i],
            HeySurname = heresamplesurnames[i],
            HeyAge = heresampleages[i],
        };
        test.OnAgeChanged += Test_OnAgeChanged;
        vs.Add(test);
    }

    YourList = vs;
    YourList.CollectionChanged += WonCollectionChanged;
}

private void Test_OnAgeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("BindMeLabel");
}
```

Note that the `WonCollectionChanged` it's not necessary any more.
Note also that the variable `vs` is not needed, you can work directly into the `YourList` object instead.

Comment: I am updating the HeyAge property, so are these changes sufficient on MyClass?
Binding BindMeLabel should be the sum of HeyAge properties.

Comment: I've edited my answer, pleas see the EDIT section. Hope it helps.